# Elasticsearch Filebeat to GCP PubSub

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-pubsub, filebeat

I want to setup the environment similar to this:
[image]
but to use GCP PubSub instead of Kafka.
I know, that Filebeat does not have a PubSub output.
What is the easiest way to achieve this? I know, that Logstash can be used to get data from Filebeat and push it to PubSub. But installing and configuring a Logstash instance on each server from which I want to gather logs seems like overkill.
Any ideas on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

Since Filebeat can't send logs to Google PubSub, you will need to use Logstash, but you don't need to install Logstash in every server, you can use a logstash pipeline to listen for your beats and ship the logs to Google PubSub, then you can use multiple logstash pipelines to consume from Google PubSub.

For example, you will have a pipeline like this one:

```
input {
    beats { *your beats configuration* }
}
output {
    google_pubsub { *your gcp pubsub configuration* }
}
```

Then, you have others pipelines to consume from gcp pubsub.

```
input {
    google_pubsub { *your gcp pubsub configuration* }
}
output {
    elasticsearch { *your elasticsearch configuration* }
}
```

You can have one Logstah server for everything just using [multiple pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiple-pipelines.html) where one pipeline will listen to beats and send to pubsub, and the others would consume from pubsub and send to elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks for hint. Although getting Logstash cluster before PubSub denies almost all PubSub pros - which could serve as a flexible load balancer and buffer for a Logstash.

Comment: Well, you will have one pipeline just to put the data into PubSub, you could use a completely different Logstash, there is not much different from sending the data directly from Filebeat if it was supported. You could also try to use fluentd to ship the logs directly to Google PubSub.